# Program to log activity in the notification area

Tags: windows, notification

I am looking for a program - ideally free and supporting Windows 7 - to log whenever an icon appears or disappears in the notification area. E.g. the log would be something like:

```
Datetime, application name, event
2014-04-25 01:02, Google Chrome, appeared 
2014-04-25 01:05, Microsoft PowerPoint, disappeared 
etc
```

If possible, it would also record the clicks in the notification area.

Comment: You may want to look at AutoHotKey. I have [a simple time tracker](https://gist.github.com/ooker777/3b2a5edacb7224ffd1f0b6ea27ca6f1b) which you may want to modify it.